# Tuning model by my metric

Tags: finetuning

My project is using a metric to evaluate the performance of regression model, it is not belong to basic metric in Machine learning (MSE,MAE,...).
So, how can I tuning model base on my metric ?

Comment: I do not quite understand. But from what I read, you can train models without that metric, split the data, and run that metric on test data to check the appropriate model. If the metric can be turned into a loss function and you are using an algorithm/tool that can adjust loss functions, then try the metric there.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which parameters you want to tune or which regression algorithm you're using. I'm going to assume that you just want to tune a few hyper-parameters.

The generic method for tuning hyper-parameters is very simple and can be implemented easily: iterate over all the combinations of values that should be tested, train and test a model using every such combination of parameters and then pick the one which obtains the best performance.

For instance if you have two parameters $A$ and $B$ with $A\in \{ a_1,a_2,a_3\}$ and $B\in \{ b_1,b_2\}$:

```
for A in { a_1, a_2, a_3 } do
  for B in { b_1, b_2 } do
    train model M with parameters A and B on the training set
    apply model M to the test set to obtain predictions
    calculate metric score on the predictions
    store score for parameters (A,B)
  done
done
pick the parameters corresponding to max performance
```

Note that after this step of parameter tuning the final model with the selected parameters should be tested on a fresh test set.

If some complex cases it's worth using a genetic algorithm instead of exploring the full space of all the parameters.